# Return a whole struct in solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Let's say I have a struct & a mapping like this:

```
    struct myStruct {
    address addr;
    uint256 price;
    bool approved;
    }

mapping(string => myStruct) mappy;
```

How can I retrieve all the keys?
I know solidity will generate getters so if I have the key I can retrieve the info from inside the struct. But the keys are unknown to me and I need to retrieve the complete struct.

Maybe a better solution would be to have a public variable which would be the size of the struct and an index has key and store the key in the struct?
That way I will know the size and I suppose I can iterate it

Comment: Try looking through https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity for suggestions on common contract design patterns. You should find a useful solution there.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you shouldn't use string as key, better declare bytes32 as string is just an alias for it.

you can make a call to the mapping giving the string key as reference.

However it will retrieve only an iterative array without the internal keynames.

let's say for example you have : 
`mappy['a']` that contains the following information

`{
    '0x000...000',
    1,
    true
   }`

the call will retrieve an simple array like this : `['0x000...000',1,true]`

If you want to make it an object you'll have to rebuild it on your own.